# Give image padding-bottom of remaining parent height

Tags: css

is it possible to give a right floated image a padding-bottom to fill the remaining parent's div height? Background: The lines under the image should be avoided. In my example padding: 100%, does what I need. It pushes the lines underneath to the left. However, the padding is running out of its parent div height (red line). Unfortunately, I can only do little changes to the markup.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.alignright {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 20px;
    float: right;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div>
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x100/000/fff" width="100px" class="alignright" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus.Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS grid for your layout:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow:dense;
}

.alignright {
  grid-column: 2; /* put the image on the right */
  margin-left: 20px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x100/000/fff" width="100px" class="alignright">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,
  nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae,
  justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in,
  viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus.Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. </div>
```